# Pointer assignment using malloc going wrong

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Please feel free to copy paste and try it out, it stops working halfway through function handget when individual hand is assigned a space in memory

```
/* 
 * A program that is meant to classify five-card poker hands. 
 *Is still in progress
 */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SEED 7
#define SIZE 5

/*
 *
 */

typedef enum suits {
   clubs,
   diamonds,
   hearts,
   spades
} suits;

typedef enum values {
    zero,
    one, // not used, but ensures numerical values correspond
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six,
    seven,
    eight,
    nine,
    ten,
    jack,
    queen,
    king,
    ace
} values; 

typedef struct cards {
    suits suit;
    values value;
} cards;

int islegal(cards *hand, int nr_of_cards);
/* Given any number of cards, determines whether any duplicates
 * or false cards are present or not. If so, returns 0, otherwise 1. 
 */
int flop(cards **handPtr); 
/* Asks the user to input a hand of cards; 
 * returns the number of cards being input
 */
int *rawtoflop (cards *handPtr, int nr_of_cards);

int hander(cards **handPtr,int counter); 

int handget(cards **playerhands,cards *thishands, int handsize);

void printsuit(suits thissuit);
/* Prints the enum-type suits
 */

void printvalue(values thisvalue);
/* Prints the enum-type values
 */

void printhand(cards *hand, int nr_of_cards); 
/* Prints a hand of cards without further processing 
*/
int main(void) {
    cards *thishand, *playerhands;

    flop(&thishand);
    printhand(thishand,6);
    handget(&playerhands,thishand,6);

    return 0;
}

int islegal(cards *hand, int nr_of_cards) {
    int i, fulldeck[4][13]={0};
    int current_value, current_suit;
    cards *current_card = hand;
    int legal = 1; 

    for (i=0; i<nr_of_cards; i++) {
        current_value = (int) (*current_card).value;
        current_suit = (*current_card).suit;

        // if the current card has value zero, it is not a valid hand
        if (current_value==0) {
            legal = 0;
            break;
        }

        //check if the current card already appears, if yes invalid hand, if no, 
        //change the flag for that card in the full deck. 
        //Since (two) will correspond to fulldeck[.][0] there is a -2 offset.
        if ( (fulldeck[current_suit][current_value - 2]) > 0 ) {
            legal = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            fulldeck[current_suit][current_value - 2]++;
        }
        current_card++;
    }

    return legal;
}

int flop(cards **handPtr) {
    int i,*q=NULL,n=NULL;
    int j[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
    int k[5]={1,1,1,1,1},nr_of_cards = 5;//for more/less cards CHANGE HERE!
    char rawsuit, rawcard[4];

    // allocate the required amount of memory for your cards
    (*handPtr) = (cards *) malloc(nr_of_cards * sizeof(cards));

    n=memcmp(j,k,sizeof(j));
    while(n!=0) {
        printf("Please input the five cards on the table: ");
        q=rawtoflop(*handPtr,nr_of_cards);
        for (i=0;i<nr_of_cards;i++) {
            j[i]=*(q+i);
        }
        n=memcmp(j,k,sizeof(j));
    }

    free(&handPtr);
    return nr_of_cards;
}

int *rawtoflop (cards *handPtr, int nr_of_cards){
    int i,m[5],*mPtr;
    char rawsuit, rawcard[4];

    mPtr=m;
        // ask for the cards
    for (i=0; i<nr_of_cards; i++)/* do */{

        scanf("%3s", &rawcard);

        rawsuit = rawcard[0]; 

        if (rawcard[1]=='1') {
            if (rawcard[2]=='0') {
                (handPtr)[i].value = ten;
            } else {
                (handPtr)[i].value = zero;
            }
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='2') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = two;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='3') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = three;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='4') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = four;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='5') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = five;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='6') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = six;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='7') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = seven;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='8') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = eight;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='9') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = nine;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='J') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = jack;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='Q') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = queen;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='K') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = king;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='A') {
            (handPtr)[i].value = ace;
        } else {
            (handPtr)[i].value = zero;
        }

        switch (rawsuit) {
            case 'h':
                (handPtr)[i].suit = hearts; 
                break;
            case 'd':
                (handPtr)[i].suit = diamonds;
                break;
            case 'c':
                (handPtr)[i].suit = clubs;
                break;
            case 's':
                (handPtr)[i].suit = spades;
                break;
            default:
                (handPtr)[i].value = zero;
        }

        m[i]=(islegal(handPtr,i+1));
    }
    return mPtr;
}


int hander(cards **handPtr,int counter) {
    int i, nr_of_cards = 2;
    char rawsuit, rawcard[4];

    if(counter==0){
        // allocate the required amount of memory for your cards
        (*handPtr) = (cards *) malloc(nr_of_cards * sizeof(cards));
    }
    // ask for the cards
    for (i=0; i<nr_of_cards; i++) do {

        scanf("%3s", &rawcard);

        rawsuit = rawcard[0]; 

        if (rawcard[1]=='1') {
            if (rawcard[2]=='0') {
                (*handPtr)[i].value = ten;
            } else {
                (*handPtr)[i].value = zero;
            }
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='2') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = two;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='3') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = three;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='4') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = four;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='5') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = five;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='6') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = six;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='7') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = seven;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='8') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = eight;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='9') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = nine;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='J') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = jack;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='Q') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = queen;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='K') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = king;
        } else if (rawcard[1]=='A') {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = ace;
        } else {
            (*handPtr)[i].value = zero;
        }

        switch (rawsuit) {
            case 'h':
                (*handPtr)[i].suit = hearts; 
                break;
            case 'd':
                (*handPtr)[i].suit = diamonds;
                break;
            case 'c':
                (*handPtr)[i].suit = clubs;
                break;
            case 's':
                (*handPtr)[i].suit = spades;
                break;
            default:
                (*handPtr)[i].value = zero;
        }
    } while (!islegal(*handPtr, i+1));

    return nr_of_cards;
}

int handget(cards **playerhand,cards *thishands, int handsize) {

    cards *player=NULL,*individualhand=NULL;
    int nr_players=1;

    (*playerhand) = (cards *) malloc(7*sizeof(cards));

    memcpy(*playerhand,thishands,handsize*sizeof(cards));

    printf("Please enter the cards for player 1: ");

    hander(&player,0);
    memcpy(*playerhand+5,player,7*sizeof(cards));

        printf("1 we made it this far chaps!!!\n");
        individualhand =(cards *) malloc(7*sizeof(cards));//THIS IS WHERE IT ALL GOES WRONG!!
        printf("2 we made it this far chaps!!\n");

    return nr_players;
}

void printsuit(suits thissuit) {
    switch (thissuit) {
        case diamonds:
            printf("d");
            break;
        case clubs:
            printf("c");
            break;
        case hearts:
            printf("h");
            break;
        case spades:
            printf("s");
            break;
        }
    return;
}

void printvalue(values thisvalue) {
    switch (thisvalue) {
        case two:
            printf("2");    
            break;
        case three:
            printf("3");
            break;
        case four:
            printf("4");
            break;
        case five:
            printf("5");
            break;
        case six:
            printf("6");
            break;
        case seven:
            printf("7");
            break;
        case eight:
            printf("8");
            break;
        case nine:
            printf("9");
            break;
        case ten:
            printf("10");
            break;
        case jack:
            printf("J");
            break;
        case queen:
            printf("Q");
            break;
        case king:
            printf("K");
            break;
        case ace:
            printf("A");
            break;
    }

    return;
}


void printhand(cards *hand, int nr_of_cards) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<nr_of_cards; i++) {
        printsuit((hand[i]).suit);
        printvalue((hand[i]).value);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using some debug tool like `gdb`?

Comment: Completely rewrite your code.

Comment: What's the question? Do you really think we are going to read your whole code, and try to guess what the question is? Provide more details, expectation, compiler output, etc...

Comment: Have you already solved [your other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402267/assigning-address-to-null-pointer-using-malloc-is-making-program-freeze-this-is)?

Comment: Check your compiler warnings, there's quite a few...

Comment: Remove all the casts before `malloc(3)` calls. Those casts haven't been necessary since 1989 when prototypes were added to the language. Having the casts in the program can hide serious errors. `<stdlib.h>` is already `#include`d, so all you need to do is remove the casts.

Comment: @Macmade 
apologies for the bad question, my other problem was not solved so I tried to rewrite the question and condense the code and get rid of some of the variables to make it look cleaner (following the advice of someone on my other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate enough space for 7 cards:

```
(*playerhand) = (cards *) malloc(7*sizeof(cards));
```

Then you copy seven cards into `*playerhand+5`:

```
memcpy(*playerhand+5,player,7*sizeof(cards));
```

So you get a buffer overflow. `*playerhand+5` is the same as `&(*playerhand)[5]`. So you're copying 7 cards into the fifth place in an array with enough capacity for 7 cards.

That's one problem of using magic number. I can't guess what this "5" means if you don't give it a name (nor why 7 cards).

Comment: apologies for the bad question, my other problem was not solved so I tried to rewrite the question and condense the code and get rid of some of the variables to make it look cleaner (following the advice of someone on my other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is not that you're copying TO `thishands` but that you are copying FROM `thishands`. You allocated `5*sizeof(cards)` to `thishands`,but when calling `handget`, you're  calling it with `handget(&playerhands,thishand,6);`. The last argument is 6, and therein lies your problem.

Get rid of all these magic numbers. Instead make them (and this is strictly because you seem to be using C not C++) #defines. That way you have a consistent number to work with.